# What are the most relevant applications of polar decomposition?

Tags: matrix-decomposition, svd, singular-values

Assume there exists a new and very efficient algorithm for calculating the polar decomposition of a matrix $A=UP$, where $U$ is a unitary matrix and $P$ is a positive-semidefinite Hermitian matrix. What would be the most relevant applications of it?

The only paper I found is [Computing the polar decomposition—with applications](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0907079?casa_token=6v3OGF6PyY4AAAAA:XTRQ6nKqz9sEmNoRj7BraVAAn0wGE0Cwcs0M1o8jL0ZFML9bzgtII_wox7jY2yGLPC5pKOoGF18), but it is 34 years old and outdated.